# How does a wavelet help in compressing data

Tags: entropy, wavelets, compression

I have an understanding of how we carry out image compression by using DCT along with Huffman encoding. The next subject is wavelets. I understand that wavelets are small waves and there are different types of wavelets. They can help store spatial and temporal data in a more efficient way. However, it is not at all clear as to how they do it.

Where can I find a simple tutorial that describes what wavelets are mathematically and how they help in data compression?

Answer (score 2):

For a very light introduction, see http://www.cybertester.com/data/wavelet.pdf
The general idea is that a family of wavelets form a basis for a space of functions, where the basis functions are bounded in both time and frequency. As with any transformation to a different basis, we have the possibility that only a (small) finite number of coefficients are significant, resulting in an efficient representation of the original function (compression).

Comment: Can you describe what basis means here and why they are supposed to be orthogonal? I shall read the text too. I do understand that like we can use complex exponentials to create any periodic function, perhaps other type of such functions exist. But as of yet, I know no other beyond the fourier series/transform.